# javascript function check box values without submit button in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert the checkbox values without submit button but i cant get my checkbox values on my jquery code please get me over this problem which jquery function i have to use to get my values i'm new this script

```
<?php

 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
 $a=date('H');

 $b=8;$c=15;
 if($b<$a&&$a<=$c)
 {

 $status='check="unchecked"';
 }
 else
 {
 $status = 'disabled="disabled"';
 }


?>
<form >
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>S.NO</p>
</td>
<td>
<p>Check Box</p>
</td>
<td>
<p>Activity Name</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Bod1" <?php echo $status ?> />
</td>
<td>
<label for="Bod1">BOD1 </label> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
2
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox"   class="get_value"value="Bod2"<?php echo $status ?> />
</td>
<td>
<label for="Bod2">BOD2 </label> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
3
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox"   class="get_value" value="Bod3"<?php echo $status ?>/>
</td>
<td>
<label for="Bod3">BOD3</label> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
4
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" value="Bod4" <?php echo $status ?>/>
</td>
<td>
<label for="Bod4">BOD4 </label> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
5
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox"  class="get_value" value="Bod5" <?php echo $status ?> />
</td>
<td>
<label for="Bod5">BOD5 </label> 
</td>
</tr>

</div>  
</div>  

</form>

<script>

$(document).ready( function () { 
      var languages=[]; 
       //$.each($("input[name='checklist[]']:checked"), function(){
      / alert($(this).val());
 // $("input[name='checklist[]']").each( function () {

         var checkedvalue=$('.check_list:checked').val();
         var checkedvalue=null;
         var inputelements=document.getelementbyclassname('check_list');
         for(var i=0;inputelements[i];i++){
         if(inputelements[i].checked){
         checkedvalue=inputelements[i].value;

           });  
          checkedvalue=checkedvalue.toString();
          $.ajax({
          url:"dummyeodcheckbox.php";
          type:"post"
          data:{languages:languages};
         success:function(data){
         var result=result.data;
         alert("function called successfully");
          }
       });
    });
 });


 </script>
```

Comment: Why are you having two variables named , checkedvalue? `var checkedvalue=$('.check_list:checked').val();`
        `var checkedvalue=null;`

Answer (score 0):

check this , hope it will help you. this is your html code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="1">value1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="2">value2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" value="3">value3</input>
</form>

<script>
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
        var ids = [];
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            ids.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: ({value: ids}),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

then create test.php file

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['value']);
?>
```

in test.php file make your action.